# Search Customer Profiles by null custom attribute value

Tags: commerce-cloud, user-profile, b2c

I have created a new custom attribute in Profile Object. It is a boolean attribute. Now I need to retrieve all customers without that attribute (`null`) or with that attribute value being `false`.

I have tried a lot of ways but it always shows me `0` results. The only way I have found to retrieve the desired profiles is by setting the attribute manually to `true` and then to `false`.

I have also tried changing the custom attribute type to `String` or `Set of Strings` but the default value does not apply to existing profiles.

Does anyone know if can I retrieve the profiles without that attribute being initialized?

Thank you all.

Comment: Please edit your question and show your code, even if it doesn't work. See [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you were probably facing is related to how Boolean values work. A Boolean can have the value "null" which is why a query in the form of

```
custom.myValue = false
```

will not work for records where the value was not explicitly set to false. A way around this is to turn the if statement around.

```
custom.myValue != true
```

This is also true for other types besides Booleans and is not reflected well in the documentation.